# Cookies not showing in Scrapy output even I have enabled it

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

By default Cookies are enabled in Python Scrapy

I have this in settings.py

```
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

It works in all other projects and shows cookies in terminal when I run code.

But it is not showing received cookies in terminal for a specific project.

I have searched internet but I am not sure what to do.

PS:

The website I am scraping of course sets cookies, I can see cookies when I visit that site from browser

What I can be missing?

Comment: does `'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware'` appear in the log for enabled downloader middlewares?

Comment: `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware` is in there when scraper starts

Comment: And you can see `Set-Cookie` headers if you print `response.headers` in your callback?

Comment: nope cant even see those

Comment: https://www.donneespersonnelles.fr/testform this is link I am scraping ... it has 1 cookie ... should have been showing in terminal .. isnt it?

Comment: Try using a browser's User-Agent (e.g. I tried with `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36`). Without a custom User-Agent, I did not get `Set-Cookie` in response headers.

Comment: i have `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'` in settings

Comment: also have `DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en',
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128297/discussion-between-paul-trmbrth-and-umair).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the dicsussions with OP, it appears that this website does not send `Set-Cookie` headers when using scrapy's default User-Agent string.

Changing the User-Agent string to something like this (in `settings.py` for example):

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36)'
```

fixes the issue.